# Does project size determine gradle build time in flutter run

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hi am new to flutter when i do flutter run command its takes about 7 minutes to run my project to the emulator for a two page  .dart file

My question, is it that as the project gets bigger the longer it takes to build when i do flutter run command.

note: my pc is a low end one

spec: 8gb ram AMD E1-6010 HP 15

Comment: use a real device instead of emulator and use vs code instead of android studio then it will take less time and for first build it would take more time but then it will be faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you run your project in the emulator or real device for the first time, flutter creates a build folder and uses it in other runs to speed up the build process or even help through hot reload. As a result, usually, it takes lower than the first time for running the project. If your project gets bigger, although it does not affect the build process very much (linearly or exponentially), it may take a little longer.

Comment: does that mean if the project gets bigger the flutter run build time would still be 7 mins tops

Comment: not exactly, but it means when your project gets twice bigger, it would not take 14 minutes (2x time!).